Why is this part not zero?
I want to simulate a modified square wave circuit. I looked at other pictures on Google and they are all similar. What is the reason for this? How can I fix this?
I expect:

I got this:



Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=urKi9OLDdCA
The schematic of my circuit:

Normally, the Primary Inductance is 29H and the total secondary inductance is 89mH.
I get this result after doubling the inductances:


What generates it?

@winny I have attached the schematic diagram of the circuit.

Your transformer based circuit is susceptible to staircase saturation unless the positive and negative pulses are exactly equally long.


What is the reason for this?

It looks like residual magnetic field left in the core of the transformer due to the magnetization inductance of the primary. Once both transistors are off, the residual field forces current into the load resistor and this creates alternating positive decays and negative decays after each transistor turns off.

How can I fix this?

If you significantly raise the number of primary and secondary turns the problem will diminish. At what point it becomes acceptable is for you to judge. You appear to be using a simulation program so try a little experiment and double the inductances to see if the problem halves.
Here is what the OP found when the transformer inductances doubled: -

If you now do a much longer run (say 20 seconds) and look at the waveform again, the upper and lower plateaus should be centred much closer to 0 volts. But, there will still be a 25 volt difference due to magnetization inductance.

Primary Inductance is 29H and the total secondary inductance is 89mH

No, that cannot be true for a step up transformer in this configuration. You have likely got the numbers back-to-front.

I doubled the inductances and simulated, but instead of approaching zero, they moved further away. Then, I divided the inductances by 2 and simulated again, but they still moved away from zero.

What coupling coefficient does your transformer have? What primary and secondary inductances did you originally have.

Normally, the Primary Inductance is 29H, the total secondary inductance is 89mH, and coupling factor is 1. The primary dc resistance and and secondary dc resistance is 1m by default.

The relative difference between the plateaus have got smaller (50 volts to about 25 volts) and that's the important thing. All that you are left with is why they are not symmetrical about 0 volts and, that is still due to residual magnetism. If you simulated for 20 seconds and took a similar snapshot they should both be centred about 0 volts. I also think you have stated your primary and secondary inductance incorrectly. The primary will be much lower than the high voltage secondary.

It works. And as you said, I got the numbers back-to-front. Thank you.

At least a part of your problem is this setting:

You have the oscilloscope set to AC coupling.  That means there's a high pass filter removing the DC from the signal.  That will cause the slanted lines in your scope pictures.
Switch to DC coupling on your oscilloscope and see if things improve.
I can't find a user's guide for the Fnirsi 138 that shows how to set the coupling.  You'll have to dig through the menus to find it.
